# How to delay an inflate with a button

Tags: java, android

Well I'm a new one in this word an I'm trying to delay an inflate because when you pressed a button an animation in other buttons happen and the inflate too.

But you cannot see animations because inflate comes quickly, so I want to delay the inflate like 2000ms so you can see first the animations and then the information that is in the inflate.

I'm using the same button for call the animations and the inflate.

Here's my code:

```
 case R.id.btnsalud:

    //This is the code for animations   

        //This is the loader for all the animations that is used for the button
        {final Animation animBounceForSalud = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.bounce);
        final Animation animBounceForSalud1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.bounce1);
        //This object is the objects (buttons) whom is applied the animation
        final Button animSalud = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnobra);
        final Button animSalud1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnprotesta);
        //This object (button) is the one which applies the animation to the other buttons
        Button btnBounceSalud = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnsalud);      
    animSalud.startAnimation(animBounceForSalud);
    animSalud1.startAnimation(animBounceForSalud1);
    animSalud.setVisibility(500);
    animSalud1.setVisibility(500);}



    //This is the code for inflate  
    //Check if the Layout already exists
    LinearLayout hiddenLayout1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.hiddenLayout);
    if((hiddenLayout1 == null)){
        //Right here is where you can defined in which layout is going to 
        //inflate the hidden layout
        LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.inflateposition0);
        View hiddenInfo = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.salud, myLayout, false);
        myLayout.addView(hiddenInfo);

    }

    break;
```

Any answer will be apreciated :D

Comment: this question is discussed before...

check this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192440/deploying-a-time-delay-for-an-inflate-layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set a Listener for the animation ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setAnimationListener(android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener) ) and only add the view when the listener reports the animation has finished.

Answer (score 0):

You can set duration parameter in your animation definition to fix how long animation should be. In Java there is setDuration(time) method and for defining animation in XML there is android:duration property.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html